# Convert OracleParameter.Value to Int32

Tags: c#, oracle, casting

I have a stored procedure call that goes like this:

```
using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Database"]))
using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("Package.Procedure", con))
{
   Int32 existsCount;

   cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
   cmd.Parameters.Add("successCount", OracleDbType.Int32, 0, ParameterDirection.InputOutput);
   cmd.Parameters.Add("BusinessId", OracleDbType.Int64, listRec.BusinessId, ParameterDirection.Input);

    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    con.Close();

    existsCount = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters["successCount"].Value);

    return (existsCount);
}
```

But on this line:

```
existsCount = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters["successCount"].Value);
```

It throws the Exception "Unable to cast object of type 'Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleDecimal' to type 'System.IConvertible'."

Any thoughts? Thanks.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

What about

```
existsCount = int.Parse(cmd.Parameters["successCount"].Value.ToString());
```

Comment: Well that's not stupid. Convert.To... should be the better choise if available. Since int.Parse() basically just parses the string value which should be a bit more overhead. However, one thing that might work too (didn't think about it in the first place) is: existsCount = (int)cmd.Parameters["successCount"].Value
if there is an explicit conversion provided by the Oracle lib.

Comment: Why TryParse? If OracleDecimal can be parsed you should be fine. If the return value is out of the int32 bounds throwing an exception is better than just silently ignoring the fact. In this special case int.Parse() is better (just my opinion).

Comment: Converting a numeric type to string only to convert it back to numeric is just wrong.

Comment: @GregZ. That's true. `Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleDecimal` should implement IConvertible in the first place so `Convert.ToInt32(...)` would succed but this gets the job done. However @Brads solution `Convert.ToInt32((decimal)(OracleDecimal)(cmd.Parameters["successCount"].Value))` is better (but four years too late :-)

Comment: The best solution is by Karim Budhwani -  OracleDecimal..ToInt32()

Comment: Using Convert.ToInt32 or OracleDecimal.ToInt32 aren't useful solutions when you don't know the type at design time.

Comment: @MarkLauter Care to explain? `Convert.ToInt32` has an `Convert.ToInt32(object value)` overload `value: An object that implements the System.IConvertible interface` In other words: You don't have to know the type at design time if the type itself properly implements `IConvertible` which is extremly useful if you don't know the type at design time.

Comment: @JürgenSteinblock The problem is that the Oracle managed types don't implement IConvertable.

public struct OracleDecimal : IComparable, INullable, IXmlSerializable

Answer (score 50):

You can also try:

```
Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleDecimal d = (Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleDecimal)cmd.Parameters["successCount"].Value;

if( d.IsNull )
    existsCount = 0;
else
    existsCount = d.ToInt32( );
```

Comment: I've tested this and it has better performance than the previous solution.

Comment: This is the most correct answer - don't know why it's all the way on the bottom.

Comment: Checking for null is a good idea and something I forgot to do.

Answer (score 5):

It is more efficient to use

```
Convert.ToInt32((decimal)(OracleDecimal)(cmd.Parameters["successCount"].Value))
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the return type at runtime because the execution code is within a cross-platform data access framework under development, so I used a switch on the parameter value type to access the underlying Oracle[type].Value property for the various Oracle managed data access types.

```
public override object GetValue(IDataParameter parameter)
{
    if (parameter == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(parameter));
    }

    // https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/win.102/b14307/OracleDbTypeEnumerationType.htm
    if (parameter is OracleParameter)
    {
        switch (parameter.Value)
        {
            case OracleBinary oracleBinary:
                // returns byte[]
                return oracleBinary.Value;
            case OracleBoolean oracleBoolean:
                // returns bool
                return oracleBoolean.Value;
            case OracleDate oracleDate:
                // returns DateTime
                return oracleDate.Value;
            case OracleDecimal oracleDecimal:
                // oracleDecimal.Value is Decimal, so we convert to correct type.
                return parameter.DbType == DbType.Decimal
                    ? oracleDecimal.Value
                    : Convert.ChangeType(oracleDecimal.Value, parameter.DbType.ToType());
            case OracleIntervalDS oracleIntervalDS:
                // returns TimeSpan
                return oracleIntervalDS.Value;
            case OracleIntervalYM oracleIntervalYM:
                // returns Long
                return oracleIntervalYM.Value;
            case OracleTimeStamp oracleTimeStamp:
                // returns DateTime
                return oracleTimeStamp.Value;
            case OracleTimeStampLTZ oracleTimeStampLTZ:
                // returns DateTime
                return oracleTimeStampLTZ.Value;
            case OracleTimeStampTZ oracleTimeStampTZ:
                // returns DateTime
                return oracleTimeStampTZ.Value;
            default:
                throw new NotSupportedException(
                    parameter.Value != null
                        ? parameter.Value.GetType().Name
                        : parameter.ParameterName);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException(parameter.GetType().Name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Would have been nice if Oracle had provided implicit conversions to the underlying native type of the Value property.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I'm using `Bulk Insert` in Oracle, and meet the same error, let me share my solution here. I solved it by adding

```
oracleCommand.ArrayBindCount = datas.Count;
```

that is I forgot to set the `ArrayBindCount` property.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you convert to `String`, and after that you convert from `String` to `Integer`.

```
Dim tmpIdSesiónCalificación As String = 
    parametroIdSesiónCalificación.Value.ToString
_idSesiónCalificación = Convert.ToInt32(tmpIdSesiónCalificación)
```